# List iterating segfault

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I have a problem with list manipulations in C++, please be indulgent with me, I'm a beginner in this language.

So, I have a list created like that :

```
list<Auction> MyAucList;
```

I construct somes objects and I put them in the list :

```
Auction test(a, i); // a and i are int
MyAucList.push_back(test); // I put my objects in the list
```

Now, in the same function, I can iterate the list and get data from the objects as :

```
for (list<Auction>::const_iterator it1 = MyAucList.begin(); it1 != MyAucList.end(); ++it1)
{
 if ((*it1).Getitem() == 118632)
   cout << "FOUND !" << endl;
}
```

This works as expected !

BUT, when I pass a reference to the list to antoher function :

```
listHandling(MyAucList);
}

void     listHandling(list<Auction> &MyAucList)
{
   for (list<Auction>::const_iterator it1 = MyAucList.begin(); it1 != MyAucList.end(); ++it1)
     {
        if ((*it1).Getitem() == 118632)
          cout << "FOUND : " << 118632 << endl;
     }
}
```

I get a segfault :-(
I tried without using a reference, or with a pointer, but same result.
Do you have an idea about this problem?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Well, for one, there is no `MyAucList` in your function; the parameter is `MyList`. Where the hell did `MyAucList` come from ? Post a *real* [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WhozCraig : Oh sorry, I made a mistake during editing my post, I edit it!

Comment: Great, now please heed the second part of that comment. My pitiful cheap glass imitation crystal ball tells me `Auction` is breaking the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), but without a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) its impossible to know for sure. We're not mind readers. Running this in a *debugger* would likely tell you *exactly* where the wheels fell off.

Comment: A fully self-contained program exhibiting the problem should be your first task, and it should generally done *before* asking the question. Often, it makes thing so blindingly obvious you won't *need* to ask :-)

Comment: Thanks for yours advices, I'll do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with *what* you're trying to do, as evidenced by the following code:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Auc {
        private: int myX;
        public:  Auc (int x) { myX = x; }
                 int GetItem () { return myX; }
};

void listHandle (list<Auc> y) {
    for (list<Auc>::const_iterator it = y.begin(); it != y.end(); ++it) {
        cout << ((Auc)*it).GetItem() << endl;
        if (((Auc)*it).GetItem() == 42)
            cout << "   Found 42\n";
    }
}

int main () {
    list<Auc>      x;
    Auc a(7);      x.push_back(a);
    Auc b(42);     x.push_back(b);
    Auc c(99);     x.push_back(c);
    Auc d(314159); x.push_back(d);

    for (list<Auc>::const_iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it) {
        cout << ((Auc)*it).GetItem() << endl;
        if (((Auc)*it).GetItem() == 42)
            cout << "   Found 42\n";
    }

    cout << "===\n";

    listHandle(x);
}
```

This quite happily prints out the data whether it's done in the same function or by a call to a different one:

```
7
42
   Found 42
99
314159
===
7
42
   Found 42
99
314159
```

Hence there's almost certainly something wrong with the *way* you're trying to do it, something that would be a lot easier to assist you with if you provided a complete example.

My suggestion is to examine my code above and try to understand it. Then you can figure out why what you have is behaving differently.